# authlogic current_user tracking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, callback, authlogic

I use authlogic for authentication and paperclip for handling user's profile picture attachments.

I use the following method to get the current_user

```
    def current_user_session
        return @current_user_session if defined?
(@current_user_session)
        @current_user_session = UserSession.find
    end

def current_user
        return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
        @current_user = current_user_session &&
current_user_session.record
    end
```

and the following after_save callback to regenerate the profile image if the image has changed.

```
   after_save do |user|
        if user.image_changed?
            Delayed::Job.enqueue ImageJob.new(user.id)
        end
    end
```

The current_user method issues a UserSession.find call and 
Looking at the docs it seems UserSession.tries to Log the user
in, which results in an update to certain fields (updated_at, token etc. but not the profile image), which results in a
save of the user record, which in my case results in after_save
callbacks firing. This after save callback checks to see if there has
been a change to user's profile image, which unnecessarily consumes time.

Now this is fine if the user indeed is trying to
update profile, but since I use current_user in many different places
within my app, this callback is getting fired (and its an expensive
call), for no reason.

I understand this isn't exactly authlogic issue, but is there anyway I
can avoid this, i.e. either not update the user record or somehow
differentiate between what is a profile update and what is an update
resulting from this UserSession.find login?

Thanks

Here is the solution that worked based on bjg's suggestion.

before_save :check_what_changed

def check_what_changed
    if self.changed.sort == ["last_request_at", "perishable_token"]
        self.skip_profile_update = true
        return true
    else
        self.skip_profile_update = false
        return true
    end
end

**Update #2
I take that back that didn't work, but it's not really a problem with this solution, for some reason paperclip tries to save the attachments even before the after_save callback. This is likely a paperclip issue, no idea..**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `before_save` callback, you could differentiate between a *real* profile change and the Authlogic related changes (`last_request_at` and `updated_at` attributes) using the Rails built-in dirty objects tracking facility. Something along these lines

```
attr_accessor :skip_profile_update

before_save do |model|
  model.skip_profile_update = (model.changed.sort == ['last_request_at', 'updated_at'])
end

after_save do |model|
  unless model.skip_profile_update
    # etc
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. The changed fields for authlogic updates are actually ['last_request_at', 'perishable_token'], there is another problem here though, the before_save callback evaluated to nil during a regular profile update and the update_attributes call in the update action fails. I can't save a regular profile with this trick.

Comment: This worked..thanks for your help!
    before_save :check_what_changed
    
    def check_what_changed
        if self.changed.sort == ["last_request_at", "perishable_token"]
            self.skip_profile_update = true
            return true
        else
            self.skip_profile_update = false
            return true
        end
    end

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with bjg's solution because sometimes I'd ONLY get 'last_request_at' and not 'updated_at' and so skip_profile_update would be false.

I changed it to this which is a whitelisted list of fields which SHOULD trigger the after_save, rather than the blacklist method. It could be easily changed to blacklist by changing the [array comparison method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002212). I also found it necessary to include all the 'true's because I was getting those dreaded "ActiveRecord record not saved" errors otherwise.

```
attr_accessor :record_activity

before_save do |user|
    user.record_activity = (user.changed & ['email', 'birthday', 'zip', 'gender']).present?
    true
  end

  after_update do |user|
    if user.record_activity
     user.send(:record_update_activity)
     true
    end
    true
  end
```